# Kafka cluster startup warning | Unable to update IO metrics | AccessDeniedException: /proc/self/io

Tags: java, linux, apache-kafka

I have a setup consisting of a 2-node Kafka KRaft Cluster on an OEL8 server, with following details :

Kafka Version : kafka_2.13-3.4.0
Java Version : OpenJDK 17

vmhost1 : server.properties

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@vmhost1:9093,2@vmhost2:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://vmhost1:9092,CONTROLLER://vmhost1:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://vmhost1:9092
```

vmhost2 : server.properties

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=2
controller.quorum.voters=1@vmhost1:9093,2@vmhost2:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://vmhost2:9092,CONTROLLER://vmhost2:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://vmhost2:9092
```

```
ls -la /proc/self/io
-r--------. 1 kafka kafkagrp 0 Nov 10 01:18 /proc/self/io
```

Upon starting the Kafka server, I've come across the following error.

```
[kafka@vmhost1 kafka_2.13-3.4.0]$ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/kraft/server.properties
[2023-11-10 00:56:43,631] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-11-10 00:56:43,902] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-11-10 00:56:44,041] WARN Unable to update IO metrics (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /proc/self/io
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2922)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3412)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3453)
        at kafka.metrics.LinuxIoMetricsCollector.updateValues(LinuxIoMetricsCollector.scala:71)
        at kafka.metrics.LinuxIoMetricsCollector.usable(LinuxIoMetricsCollector.scala:91)
        at kafka.server.KafkaBroker.$init$(KafkaBroker.scala:106)
        at kafka.server.BrokerServer.<init>(BrokerServer.scala:74)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.<init>(KafkaRaftServer.scala:80)
        at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:85)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:93)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2023-11-10 00:56:44,050] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-11-10 00:56:44,053] INFO Starting controller (kafka.server.ControllerServer)
[2023-11-10 00:56:44,064] WARN Unable to update IO metrics (kafka.server.ControllerServer)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /proc/self/io
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2922)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3412)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3453)
        at kafka.metrics.LinuxIoMetricsCollector.updateValues(LinuxIoMetricsCollector.scala:71)
        at kafka.metrics.LinuxIoMetricsCollector.usable(LinuxIoMetricsCollector.scala:91)
        at kafka.server.ControllerServer.startup(ControllerServer.scala:142)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.$anonfun$startup$1(KafkaRaftServer.scala:98)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.$anonfun$startup$1$adapted(KafkaRaftServer.scala:98)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRaftServer.startup(KafkaRaftServer.scala:98)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:115)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I have tried changing permissions but it's not permitted even with sudo

```
chmod 640 /proc/self/io
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/proc/self/io’: Operation not permitted
```

Kindly help me with solution or some suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked what user & group the process was running by?

Comment: @appchemist Yes, the process is running with `kafka` user which has read permission to /proc/self/io.

`
ps -p 2400932 -o user,group
USER     GROUP
kafka    kafkagrp
`

Comment: `/proc/self` is always tied to process accessing it. attempt to change it for other program is like sharing http://localhost to someone in internet

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/self` means `/proc/{pid}`

check it out [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

So, chmod command's `/proc/self` is not kafka process's `/proc/self`

Exactly, you change `/proc/{kafka process pid}/io`

But changing permissions is not a perfect solution because OS creates a new `/proc/{pid}` every time you run the program.

The link below looks like a similar issue, check it out
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297190/owner-cant-read-proc-pid-io